# Cordova camera plugin do not resize

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm up to date with the cordova camera plugin but it is not working the resize or the quality change, I tried with JPEG and PNG but nothing.

```
$ ionic plugin ls
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
com-badrit-base64 0.2.0 "Base64"
com.googlemaps.ios 2.1.1 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

And some code

```
$scope.take_picture = function()
{
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
    var options = {
        quality: 25,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: false,
        targetHeight: 200,
        targetwidth: 200
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
        $scope.image_uri = imageURI;
        $scope.marcar_gps();
        $cordovaCamera.cleanup(); 
        window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.image_uri, function(base64){
            $scope.base64 = base64.split("data:image/png;base64,")[1]
        });
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('error ',err);
      $cordovaCamera.cleanup();
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

    return true;
};
```

The picture size i'm getting is 2448 × 3264

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
quality: 50
```

Compression quality (0-100: 0=low quality & high compression, 100=compress of max quality). It doesn't change image resolution.

```
targetHeight: 200,
targetwidth: 200
```

For me specifying this only works with JPEG option, and also I have `DestinationType.DATA_URL` if that changes something.

Comment: Hi Luka, thanks for the answer, as I said on the question I tried with JPEG and PNG but nothing. Also worked with data_url but that make a issue with some phones. But still none of those make changes on resolution